# Check if i already has bookmarked this page on Delicious

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, delicious

Is there a way to get som kind of indication in Firefox (perhaps an icon in the statusbar) on whether i've already saved the current page on my delicious account.

Now i have to try to save it, and then it tells me that i already saved this page. I would rather know this in advance.

Thanks!

edit: 
Furtelwart:
That seems to be the missing piece for me; i use the del.icio.us addon for FF, but firefox bookmarks and delicious bookmarks are not synced whatsoever. How can i enable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an [del.icio.us addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/3615) you will see it when you look at your address bar.
It is filled if you have bookmarked it yet:

[image]

Comment: I think this happens only when you have delicious integrated with your firefox bookmarks.

Comment: As I stated in my answer.

Comment: Umm, not really. Your answer describes getting the addon which will integrate it with firefox. When you integrate it with the bookmarks, the addon will keep your firefox-bookmarks synchronized with your delicious login (you can lookup without Internet access then).

Comment: I think the addon will "integrate it with the bookmarks". If the addon synchronizes the bookmarks, you will see the star if you have bookmarked it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall, the regular delicious addon will pull out the bookmark when you try to tag it if its already bookmarked in your login. This is possible because the bookmark data has hash information in its meta-fields.

Which is of course what you are experiencing.

Is that a problem?

If you have your favorites locally stored, it will probably not even require a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

This thingy solved my problem.

[dejalicious ++](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/9433)

My firefox and delicious bookmarks is not synced and can't figure out how to sync them, so this is better for me.